# Angular JS - Not adding content in ng-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am new to Angular and I am having issues with Routing. When I go to localhost/index.html#/chatroom, it doesn't load Chatroom.html. Please consider the following files. Any help would be appreciated.

Following is my core.js file:

```
var messagingApp = angular.module('messagingApp',['ngRoute']);

function mainController($scope) {

 console.log("yay");

}

function routing($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/chatroom', {
        templateUrl : 'templates/ChatRoom.html',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    });
}
messagingApp.config(routing);
messagingApp.controller('mainController',mainController);
```

Following is my index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular-route.js"></script>

    <script src="js/User.js"></script>
    <script src="js/core.js"></script>

    <title>Real Time Chat</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="messagingApp">
<p>ss</p>

<div ng-view>

</div>
```

Following is my ChatRoom.html:

```
<div class="row">
    <p>ssss</p>
    <ul class="users">
        <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.UserName }}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Directory structure:

```
-js
  core.js

-templates
 ChatRoom.html

-index.html
```

Going to localhost/index.html#chatroom should load that file as per my understanding but it doesn't.

Comment: getting any errors in console?

Comment: @SaEChowdary None

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't used localhost/index.html#chatroom. Please changed it to localhost/#/chatroom

Comment: no it shows "ss" from the <p></p> tag before the ng-view div

Comment: Look like it could not found the routing instead. Please change you code to this .. messagingApp.config(function ($routeProvider) { // Routing code here });

Comment: Still nothing. One thing to note is that when I press on "http://localhost:8080/#/chatroom" it changes it to "http://localhost:8080/#!#%2Fchatroom" but that was happening before the last change as well

Comment: What? invalid char is added in front routing path. Try using html5 mode that can cut all hashtag. Set this code in under $routingProvider. $locationProvider.html5Mode({enabled: true, requireBase: false, rewriteLinks: true})

Comment: and change the url to localhost:8080/chatroom

Comment: I think that your angular-route library has something wrong. Please try to use other version of angular-route as well.

Comment: Thanks but still nothing changes. It is still modifying the url. Can you please provide a cdn of the route library that you think is right?

Comment: You can install bower package manager and install the latest stable angular and angular-route into your project. Notice that when you install angular-route, bower can find easily which angular is suitable for itself without conflict.

Comment: answer is irrelevant

Answer (score -1):

Add your script tags after ng-view div

Comment: which script tags? all of them?

Comment: @fur866 Yes all script tag below ng-view